# Angular 2 - pass object from parent to child component to modify

Tags: angular, parent-child

I know that sending an object from parent component to it children component is as easy as sending it through the @input.

In my case I need to send an object from parent to its child and have it changed at the child side and see this change in the parent side immediately.

In fact I want to send the reference of the object to the child not its value.

Comment: Pass the object as an `@Input` to the child. Any modification made to it in the child will also apply to the object in the parent (as long as the "object" is not a number, a string or a boolean).

Comment: I already have tried it but the modification by the child does not modify it on the parent. What do you mean by object should not be a number, string or boolean?

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question: how you define the object, how you pass it to the child component, and how you modify it in the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of parent-child communication, we will see in the console that the changed value from child of the passed object from parent has changed.

**Parent component:**

```
import { Component, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <child [childProp]="parentProp" (childPropChange)="fromChild($event)"></child>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
  parentProp = {value1: "value1", value2: "value2"};

  ngOnChanges(c: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('Parent changes: This doesnt happen often ', c);
  }

  fromChild(val) {
    console.log('Parent: receive from child, ', val.value1);
    console.log('Parent: receive from child, ', val.value2);
    console.log('Parent: receive from child, ', this.parentProp.value1);
    console.log('Parent: receive from child, ', this.parentProp.value2);
  }
}
```

**Child component:**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <h3>Child Component with {{childProp}}</h3>
    <button (click)="fire()">Talk to parent</button>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() childProp;
  @Output() childPropChange = new EventEmitter<{}>();

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('in child changes with: ', changes);
  }

  fire() {
    this.childProp.value1 = "value1 changed";
    this.childProp.value2 = "value2 changed";
    this.childPropChange.emit(this.childProp);
  }
}
```

You can see the result in [This stackblidtz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-communication-nate-vmqms6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

In the parent component we have this object:

```
parentProp = {value1: "value1", value2: "value2"};
```

In the child component, we change the received object from parent and emit the value this way:

```
this.childProp.value1 = "value1 changed";
this.childProp.value2 = "value2 changed";
this.childPropChange.emit(this.childProp);
```

You can see this result in the console:

```
Parent: receive from child,  value1 changed
Parent: receive from child,  value2 changed
Parent: receive from child,  value1 changed
Parent: receive from child,  value2 changed
```